# Do the western boundaries of Rohan as given in "Unfinished Tales," Cirion and Eorl (iii), make sense?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

On page 305 of *Unfinished Tales*, there is a passage regarding the boundaries of Rohan:

> The bounds of the realm of Eorl were to be: in the West the river Angren from its junction with the Adorn and thence northwards to the outer fences of Angrenost, and thence westwards and northwards along the eaves of Fangorn Forest to the river Limlight; and that river was its northern boundary, for the land beyond had never been claimed by Gondor.

Here, it is stated that the western boundaries of Rohan extend from Isengard 'westwards and northwards along the eaves of Fangorn Forest to the river Limlight'. How can this be true, given that Fangorn is to the east of Isengard?

Comment: Given what you said, it sounds like an error.  It might be helpful to quote a longer segment of text, though so the context of the quote is clear.

Comment: 'The bounds of the realm of Eorl were to be: in the West the river Angren from it's junction with the Adorn and thence northwards to the outer fences of Angrenost, and thence westwards and northwards along the eaves of Fangorn Forest to the river Limlight; and that river was its northern boundary, for the land beyond had never been claimed by Gondor.

Answer (score 6):

#### Westwards and Northwards is indeed correct

Looking at the map of Middle-earth, Fangorn is East of Isengard and located Northwest of Rohan's boundaries:

[image]

As you can see from the passage *westwards and northwards along the eaves of Fangorn Forest* should be intrepreted as the boundaries of Rohan running along (but not including) Fangorn along its (Rohan's, not Fangorn's) westward and northward points.

Here's the closeup of the River [Limlight](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Limlight) which extends from the Anduin along the northern boundary of Rohan:

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, it means that the "westward boundary" is fangorn, not that you'd be going west if you walked along the border's path.

Comment: @ibid Yep! Tolkien started off that passage with the rivers Angren and Adorn, followed by Fangorn and then Limlight. So if you look at it that way he's describing the boundaries from bottom left to top right (w.r.t. the first map).

Comment: Thank you for your response, the Steadfast! So I guess that what Tolkien meant was this: go from Isengard and then along the westward and northward eaves of Fangorn?

Comment: @Ben Westwards in the sense that, if you look at the map, the boundary of Rohan where it touches Fangorn forest is its westward and northern boundary. See ibid's comment above ^ take the passage as **an overview of the map** rather than looking at it as if you're walking from Isengard to Meduseld

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you'd like you can click the green arrow under the upvote system of my answer to mark it as the Accepted answer!

Comment: I don't see anyway to read this quote as saying that "thence westwards and northwards" should be interpreted as starting from a point east of Angrenost and spreading in two opposite directions, rather than at Angrenost itself.

Comment: I disagree with the answer. "Angrenost, thence westwards" has to be wrong. That takes you towards Dunland.